# How to migrate a tomcat webapp to jetty

Tags: java, jetty, tomcat7

I have the following host entry in my server.xml for tomcat

```
<Host name="app.andrewbucknell.com" appBase="webapps"
       unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
       xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
  <Context path="" docBase="app" debug="5"/>
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
         prefix="app_access_log." suffix=".txt"
         pattern="common"/>
  <Resource name="jdbc/appDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
               username="appuser" password="apppass" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/appDB"/>
</Host>
```

I am trying to move to Jetty but cant figure out where to put the resource declaration.

What I want is for the resource declaration to wind up being server specific rather than app specific. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert of jetty, but from their [documentation page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_JNDI_Datasource#MySQL) you could achieve what you want by creating a jetty.xml or WEB-INF/jetty-env.xml file and define the datasource in it as follows:

```
<New id="jdbc/appDB" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
 <Arg></Arg>
 <Arg>jdbc/appDB</Arg>
 <Arg>
    <New class="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver">
       <Set name="Url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/appDB</Set>
       <Set name="User">appuser</Set>
       <Set name="Password">apppass</Set>
    </New>
 </Arg>
</New>
```